# How to extract process hierarchy information in linux?

Tags: linux, session, process, hierarchy

I want to write a program in Linux which by getting a session id could print all processes and process groups in that session in a tree view structure!?

How can I extract such information!? Should I resort to proc file system?

Comment: Which programming language would you be using? Scanning /proc is a generic way that would work will all languages, otherwise you can use system calls if you are working with C/C++.

Comment: @ Shamit Verma I am using C. Using system calls could be lot more easier, i think!? i searched the internet for some clue, but nothing!

Comment: Why do people say "resort to /proc" as if it's some kind of evil hack?  It's there to be used; use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (all?) Linux programs read `/proc` to know about running processes.

If you are using Perl, then may be [Proc::ProcessTable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Proc%3a%3aProcessTable%3a%3aProcess) cpan module may save you some work.

Edit: Since you are using C, then you can look at [pstree source code](http://www.thp.uni-duisburg.de/pstree/pstree.c) to get inspiration.